# Linebreak not working - Python

Tags: python, list, linked-list, line-breaks

Somehow the linebreaks are not working as they should.
This is what I get:

```
Expected:
    O meu u2 2 post
    http://www.yahoo.com
    1 Gosto, 0 Nao gosto
    <BLANKLINE>
    O meu u2 post
    http://www.altavista.com
    1 Gosto, 0 Nao gosto
Got:
    'O meu u2 2 post\nhttp://www.yahoo.com\n1 Gosto, 0 Nao Gosto\n\nO meu u2\nhttp://www.yahoo.com\n1 Gosto, 0 Nao Gosto'
```

This is the code used in the function.
The important parts should be the str and showRecentComments functions

```
class Comments():
def __init__(self, u=None, text='', link=None):
    self.u = u
    self.text = text
    self.link = link
    self.topo = None
    self.fim = None

def __str__(self):
    actual = self.topo
    s = ''
    if actual == None:
        return None
    while actual != None:
        if actual.seg == None:
            s += str(actual)
            actual = actual.seg
        else:
            s += str(actual) + '\n' + '\n'
            actual = actual.seg
    return s

def add(self,comment):
    if self.topo == None:
        self.topo = comment
        self.fim = comment
    else:
        comment.seg = self.topo
        self.topo.ant = comment
        self.topo = comment

def remove(self,comment):
    actual = self.topo
    if (self.topo == self.fim) and (self.topo == comment):
        self.topo = None
        self.fim = None
    while actual!=None:
        if actual == comment:
            if self.topo==comment:
                actual.seg.ant = None
                self.topo = actual.seg
            elif self.fim==comment:
                actual.ant.seg = None
                self.fim = actual.ant
            else:
                actual.seg.ant = actual.ant
                actual.ant.seg = actual.seg
            break
        else:
            actual = actual.seg

def countLike(self):
    count = 0
    actual = self.topo
    while actual != None:
        if len(actual.likeList) >= 1:
            count += 1
            actual = actual.seg
        else:
            actual = actual.seg
    return count

def showRecentComments(self,n):
    count = 1
    actual = self.topo
    sC = ''
    if actual == None:
        return None
    while actual != None:
        if count < n:
            sC += str(actual) + '\n' + '\n'
            count += 1
            actual = actual.seg
        elif count == n:
            sC += str(actual)
            count += 1
            actual = actual.seg
        elif count > n:
            break 
    return sC
```

Regards, Nelson Gregório

Comment: "This is what I get:" .. well, what do you do?

Comment: You should not return `None` from `__str__`, instead, return `''`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're looking at the representation of the string, which will show you the newline characters as `\n`.  If you `print` or write to e.g. stdout (`sys.stdout.write(s)`) the string instead, the newlines will be expanded.

Comment: The __str__ function works though.
Should showRecentComments do the same?
-----
Print instead of return works indeed.
I guess it'll do.

Comment: `return` still makes sense, but you want to `print` the string that is returned.  e.g. if you had `c` as an instance of your `Comments` class, you could then do `print c`, which would use `__str__` to get a string representation of said instance and print that.